# Выравнивание всплывающих элементов в scrollView по центру дисплея

Tags: android, android-scrollview, scrollview

В `scrollView` добавлен `framelayout`, а в него `linearlayout1` с несколькими `view`, прокручивающимися вверх/вниз, и `linearLayout2` для контейнера увеличенного `view`.

Т.е. каждое `view` может увеличиваться при клике на него, и когда это происходит, появляется контейнер `linearLayout2`, который который изначально невидим.

Можно ли как-то  контейнер `linearLayout2` разместить по центру экрана (дисплея)? Дело в том, что все layoutParams (в том числе gravity) предусматривают выравнивание дочернего элемента относительно родителя, а тут нужно выравнивание относительно экрана, т.е. так, чтобы появляющийся при клике `linearLayout2` имел отступ сверху =0 от верхнего края дисплея и занимал всю доступную ширину и высоту дисплея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта. Первый - создать кастомный `DialogFragment` и прицепить к нему `linearLayout2`, при этом установку размеров необходимо производить в `onResume()` фрагмента. Второй вариант - использовать `WindowManager` для создания так называемого `System overlay window`. Второй вариант более гибок, но существуют определенные проблемы с разрешениями для API 23+.

Comment: С DialogFragment  все вроде бы получилось, но так и не смогла понять, как  в самом DialogFragment  обработать тег, который был передан ему из активити в методе show? Как  получить этот тег в самом фрагменте?

Comment: Аргументы в `DialogFragment` передаются формированием обычного `Bundle` с последующим `dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle)`. Ну и соответственно `getArguments()` в самом фрагменте

Comment: кстати, Вы неправы, получить тег можно String tag = this.getTag();